# Use Channel API to receive messages from task in Task Queue

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine, python-2.7, channel, channel-api

I am trying to figure out the Task Queue and Channel API.

I have a process that is expected to run >60 seconds added to the task queue when the user submits a form. This process should then send messages through the channel api as it executes. Of coarse I cannot seem to make this work. Can anyone tell me why the `SendMessagesHandler` is not able to  send messages to the client side javascript? Or perhaps the client side javascript is not receiving properly? Also, I do not see the `logging` messages from `SendMessagesHandler` in the Log Console, it only shows the run of the mill `INFO ... GET` or `POST`. As I write this I am realizing that I must have more than one issue going on here, the task does get created in the task queue, I can see it in the SDK console, however it seems to just keep running endlessly, I would expect it to run for roughly 1m2sec. If I take out the `sleep` commands from `SendMessageHandler` it runs to quickly to even catch it in the SDK console.

Thanks in advance for your help.

Here is the main.py file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import webapp2
import os
import jinja2
import logging
from time import sleep
from google.appengine.api import taskqueue, users, channel
from google.appengine.ext import db

class MainHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        if user:
            key = self.request.get('key')
            if not key:
                key = user.user_id()
            key_link = 'http://localhost:8080/?key=' + key
            token = channel.create_channel(key)
            template_values = {'token': token,
                    'me': user.user_id(),
                    'key': key,
                    'key_link': key_link,
                    'initial_message': 'Nothing to show yet'}
            template = jinja_environment.get_template('template.html')
            self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))
        else:
            self.redirect(users.create_login_url(self.request.uri))

    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        taskqueue.add(url='/sendmessages', params={'key': key})
        self.redirect('/')

class SendMessagesHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        key = self.request.get('key')
        sleep(2)
        channel.send_message(key, 'Starting to send messages...')
        logging.info('Starting to send messages...')
        i = 0
        while i < 60:
            i += 1
            logging.info('Counter incremented.')
            channel.send_message(key, 'Counter incemented.')
            sleep(1)

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
        loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([
        ('/', MainHandler),
        ('/sendmessages', SendMessagesHandler)
    ], debug=True)
```

and here is the template.html

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Simple Task Queue Channel API</title>
        <script src='/_ah/channel/jsapi'></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type='text/jacascript'>
            onOpened = function() {};
            onMessage = function(message) {
                var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox");
                messageBox.innerHTML = message;
            };
            onError = function() {};
            onClose = function() {};
            channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('{{token}}');
            socket = channel.open();
            socket.onopen = onOpened;
            socket.onmessage = onMessage;
            socket.onerror = onError;
            socket.onclose = onClose;
        </script>
        <form method="post" action="/">
            <input type="text" name="key" value="{{ key }}">
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Receive Messages">
        </form>
        <div id="messageBox"><!-- message should go in here --></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the view source from the browser:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Simple Task Queue Channel API</title>
    <script src='/_ah/channel/jsapi'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type='text/jacascript'>
        onOpened = function() {};
        onMessage = function(message) {
            var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox");
            messageBox.innerHTML = message;
        };
        onError = function() {};
        onClose = function() {};
        channel = new goog.appengine.Channel('channel-2840733866-1367208241-185804764220139124118');
        socket = channel.open();
        socket.onopen = onOpened;
        socket.onmessage = onMessage;
        socket.onerror = onError;
        socket.onclose = onClose;
    </script>
    <form method="post" action="/">
        <input type="text" name="key" value="185804764220139124118">
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Receive Messages">
    </form>
    <div id="messageBox"><!-- message should go in here --></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I spot at least two errors:

First

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
```

Second

```
onMessage = function(message) {
        var messageBox = document.getElementById("messageBox");
        messageBox.innerHTML = message.data;
    };
```

Comment: Wow, i should have gotten some sleep before I posted that. Thanks dragonx, that was all it took! I posted this on github for anyone else who may be having difficulty getting up and running with channel-api: https://github.com/forestcoder/simple-task-queue-channel-api