# How can i get Task notification on UI

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging, google-tasks

I working in Google App engine with JAVA API.
User can upload file in my web app and then I am creating a task to process the file.
Now I need a way by which I can show the overall task progress in UI.
How can I do this.

Do I have to use `push notification or SignalR` or Cloud Messaging will be help full in this case.

Thanks in advance

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16270345/use-channel-api-to-receive-messages-from-task-in-task-queue and find out how you can do it in Java

Comment: Do you mean a progress bar to show the progress of the uploading of file?